# Bookmarklet for github gist paste service?

Tags: api, github, posterous, gist

I would like something like in posterous, for example (see [here](http://blog.posterous.com/the-new-posterous-bookmarklet)). Just a link on my browser that allows me to grab the code or pre blocks inside a web page, and choose the one to add to my gists.

Anybody knows if something similar exists? How can I do it? Do I need the gist API (not very usable because of lack of documentation)?

Thanks a lot for any direction!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look to the pastebin chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ghipmampnddcpdlppkkamoankmkmcbmh?hl=es